# Azure Frontdoor Dynamic Header

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

I'm using Azure Frontdoor and want to inspect the querystring for a key paid, and if it is present, use it in an Response Header.

For example, if the request comes in to `https://example.com/?foo=bar`, I'd like to return a header that uses this querystring value, ie: `X-Foo-Header: bar`

Is this possible?

I note I can access the `{query_string}` server variable in the Response Header action, but am unsure if Frontdoor has support to enable any type of dynamic inspection of that value. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/rule-set-server-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one field in the query string and you know it ahead of time you can use the `query_string` server variable.  You can use the offset to get only the value and return it in the predefined response header.  This example rule set works for your example:

[image: implemented rule]

Query url string from a Chrome Incognito window:
[image: query string url]

Result in Chrome Developer Tools:  [image]

If you're wanting it to parse the query string field dynamically into an 'X-something-Header' I don't believe it's possible right now.  You'd have to dynamically set the offset value and be able to parse the query string to determine the position of the '=' character.

Comment: Thanks - yeah thats as I suspected and doesnt look like its a capability of frontdoor to pull query string elements out elegantly.